# Database scheme for searching my age groups

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I've struggled with this for a while now trying to figure out how to do this most efficiently.

The problem is as follows. I have items in a database to be marketed for specific age groups such as `ages 10 to 20` or `ages 16+` and I need to be able to make a query like, `find item that is for 17 year old`

Here are my two best ideas (but I don't like either, as I think they're both inefficient).

1. Have a csv column with values like `10-20` and `16+` , retrieve the entire list, and parse through it (Bad idea, I know, I'm fresh out of ideas here though)
2. Have a csv column with values like `10,11,12,13...20` for ranges, so I can look for it using `WHERE ages LIKE "%17%"`, and for cases like `16+` I'd have to retrieve those special cases using something like `WHERE ages LIKE "%+%"` and parse through those.

I'm of course leaning towards the second option, but in the very best scenario, I'm running two queries one for regular items, and one for things like `16+`

Is there a better way? If not, do you think you could make either of my models more efficient? Thanks.

Comment: Which database? And please remove "csv column" from your vocabulary, that sort of thing is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I realize this, but like I said I'm way out of ideas here. Thank's for you're help though :D

Comment: I hope you're storing the DOB in the database, rather than the age (with maybe the age as a computed column)?

Comment: @Damien: I think the target age is a variable, the table holds fixed age *ranges*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Add `lower_age` and `upper_age` columns to your table, both integers that allow NULLs.
2. If `lower_age` is NULL then there is no lower bound.
3. If `upper_age` is NULL then there is no upper bound.
4. Combine COALESCE and BETWEEN for your queries.

To clarify (4), you want to say things like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where $n between coalesce(lower_age, $n) and coalesce(upper_age, $n)
```

where `$n` is the age you're looking for. BETWEEN uses inclusive bounds so `coalesce(lower_age, $n)` ignores `$n` if `lower_age` is not NULL and gives you `$n >= $n` (i.e. an automatic true on that bound) if `lower_age` is NULL; similarly for the `upper_age`.

If something is suitable for only 11 year olds, then your `[lower_age,upper_age]` closed interval would be `[11, 11]`, 16+ would be `[16, NULL]`, six and lower would be `[NULL, 6]`, everyone would be `[NULL, NULL]`, and no one would be `[23, 11]` or anything else with `lower_age > upper_age` (or, more likely, invalid data that a CHECK constraint would throw a hissy fit over).

Comment: Beautiful solution @muistooshort , simple and to the point. Thank's for the full the description too, it helped a lot :D . I love SO !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways.  If you store the age of the user(whatever) in the row.  Then you can query the age and with > 16 or < 30 or between 10-20 whatever. The other option is to store this as a bitwise.  Have a reference table and store your different ranges if they can have multiples then you just add the two row values together.

```
1 = 10
2 = 16+
4 = 10-20
8 = 20-30
16 = 20+
32 = 30+
.
.
.
.
```

then in the table that stores the persons info you can set the column to an int or bigint take your preference and then for whatever groups they belong to you can determine this by the number for example:

```
Table of Users
ID     Name        BitWise
 1     test          2
 2     something     6 (2+4)
 3     blah          24 (8+16)
```

However I think that it may be a bit overkill with the bitwise you might be best just storing the age as a number an running queries against that.  More than likely this will be the most efficient.

Comment: With your solution, if I were to search for something that is for a 22 year old, I'd have to retrieve the entire table, and parse through each option because for example 22 would fall under 16+, 20-30, 20+ .

At least that's what I got, am I getting this wrong? Thank's for your help btw.

Comment: If your rdbms supports bitmap indexes, you won't have to retrieve the entire table. You'll have the bitmap index in memory and use bitwise operations on them. Still a full table scan of sorts, but no harddisk penalty.

Comment: @vvMINOvv wellenborn stated it right if your table is indexed and your RDBMS supports indexes then you will actually have this cached and so no hdd hit.  However you would only use this if you need to know that the person falls into multiple categories. if it will always only be one category then I would just stick with storing the age in the row and querying against that.

Comment: Thank's for your help @CBRRacer , I'll definitely be using that solution but for something else. For my intents and purposes this might be a bit overkill. Thank's again :D

Answer (score 1):

You have a range of options (no pun intended). For age recommendations, the easiest way is to store a min_age and max_age and query like this:

```
select * from item where :age between min_age and max_age
```

where you have to decide whether you allow nulls for these columns (then you need to use coalesce() or nvl() or whatever function your database provides for dealing with comparisons with nulls), or set boundary values for these columns where you can be sure :age will always fall in between.

Alternatively, you can use a m:n table

```
create table item_ages (item_id int not null, age int not null, constraint item_ages_pk primary key (item_id, age)
```

and fill it with explicit values:

```
item_id | age
-------------
      1 | 16
      1 | 17
      1 | 18
```

and so on. This is more cumbersome tha using a range, but also more flexible, and since your database can index the table and probably store that index in memory, queries should be fast. You only have to touch this table when a new item is entered or the age range for a particular item changes.

Note that CBRRacer's answer has similar properties: both share the idea that you prepare a datastructure that can easily be indexed, and answer the filter question from that index. This is a popular method for storing marketing data in ecommerce applications. The extreme end of that range would be to use a dedicated package for storing inverted indexes for that purpose. But for a simple age recommendation that's of course overkill.

Comment: thank's @wallenborn I'll be researching your solution as well. Cheers.

Comment: I can't stop learning it seems! @wallenborn thank's for the explanation of your reasoning, it was incredibly helpful. I feel I'm going to use this m:n concept in another table I have in this project.  Thank you very much for all your help :D

Comment: @vvMINOvv: You're in the wrong place if you want to stop learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Someting like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE 17 BETWEEN start_age AND end_age
```

Comment: And how would you handle the "16+" or "under 5" cases?